# Copy all files, skip those already existing, and delete those in destination not in source

Tags: windows, robocopy

I imagine this could be done with Robocopy - I want to copy my music library from its folder on my PC to my mp3 player. I have ~5000 songs, and I'll probably run the copy every time I add an album.

Now, just using Windows copy, I can say to skip pre-existing files and it will do so and run relatively fast. However, I want my destination (mp3 player) to reflect **deleted** music as well. I'm not sure if simply using a mirror command would do this - I assumed that wouldn't take into account pre-existing files.

Quick example:

Source folder:

```
song1.mp3
song3.mp3
song4.mp3
```

Destination folder BEFORE copying:

```
song1.mp3
song2.mp3
song3.mp3
```

Destination folder AFTER copying (Identical to source):

```
song1.mp3
song3.mp3
song4.mp3
```

The important point is that, while copying, `song1.mp3` and `song3.mp3` were skipped (NOT overwritten, or the copy will take forever - because I have many songs) and `song2.mp3` was deleted.

Comment: What file system is the source and target? If both are NTFS a simple [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) `/MIR` command will do exactly what you describe. It won't overwrite existing files. For example my own command looks like `robocopy.exe "T:\music" "S:\music" /MIR /W:1 /R:1 /MT:8 /NDL`. If your target file system is FAT you [face a problem](http://www.conetrix.com/Blog/post/Robocopy-Incorrectly-Detects-Files-as-Newer-When-Copying-Between-Different-File-Systems.aspx) which can be solved with the switch `/FFT`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this:

```
robocopy <Source> <Destination> /E /COPY:DAT /XO /PURGE /R:1 /W:1
```

From robocopy's help:

```
/PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.
/XO :: eXclude Older files.
```

Comment: Why `/xo`? Wouldn't `/purge` suffice? Additionally, if OP has folders (e.g. albums), they'll probably want `/e` (or `/s`) too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task for a backup software.  I haven't tried it, but [cwrsync](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync#) looks OK to me.  It's a Windows packaging of a battle-tested F/OSS tool [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) with a GUI as a nice bonus.

Note that on the page I linked they say that "You must, however, have a working ssh system.", but I would not take it literally, the software should not refuse to operate short of ssh if both points are local.

Answer (score 0):

All that you have to do is to run Robocopy with the `/MIR` option:

```
robocopy SOURCE DESTINATION /MIR
```

If you want a verbose output, add `/ETA /V`:

```
robocopy SOURCE DESTINATION /MIR /ETA /V
```

If you want to force Robocopy to copy only MP3 files, add the `/IF` option:

```
robocopy SOURCE DESTINATION /MIR /ETA /V /IF *.mp3
```

If your destination's filesystem is FAT (16, 32 or 64), add the `/FFT` option:

```
robocopy SOURCE DESTINATION /MIR /ETA /V /IF *.mp3 /FFT
```

The command `robocopy /?` provides a full list of available options.